# Checking if value ​exist within text between string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this text in one varchar2 column:

```
\nAAAA BBB: XXX ZZZ;
\nDDDD DDD: UUU III;
\nAAAA BBB: YYY XXX;
\nDDDD DDD: UUU III;
```

I have to pull out of the table all the records that have values in the column:

1) XXX in the first place

2) XXX in second place

3) XXX XXX in both place.

I am interested only in sequences of signs beginning with:  `\nAAAA BBB:` do `;`

How to do it in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a string match.  You can do what you describe with `LIKE`:

```
select t.*
from t
where col like '\nAAAA BBB:%XXX%'
```